# [Vue warn]: Maximum recursive updates exceeded in component

Tags: typescript, vue.js, reactive, quasar, pinia

In my Vue/Quasar project I am trying to fetch data from a server before rendering a component. Within this component I have a  that uses the fetched data as rows. The data fetch takes place in a Pinia store and a related state property represents the data received.

As soon as the data fetch happens, I get the warning mentioned in the title.

So this is my Pinia store where the data is fetched from the server:

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia';
import { AssetDTOOutput } from 'src/libraries/openapi';
import { AssetApi } from 'src/libraries/openapi/apis/AssetApi';
const assetApi: AssetApi = new AssetApi();

export const useAssetStore = defineStore({
  id: 'assetStore',
  state: () => ({
    assetList: [] as AssetDTOOutput[],
  }),

  getters: {},

  actions: {
    async fetchAssetList() {
      this.assetList = await assetApi.getAssetListAssetListGet();
      console.log('Asset list was fetched');
    },
  },
});
```

This is a part of the parent component where the component containing the  is redered.
I have tried to ensure that the table component is only redered when the data is fetched.

```
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <table-component v-if="assetListIsFetched"></table-component>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </q-page>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue';
import TableComponent from 'src/components/TableComponent.vue';
import AddAssetDialogComponent from 'src/components/inputFieldSections/AddAssetDialogComponent.vue';
import { useAssetStore } from 'src/stores/assetStore';

const assetStore = useAssetStore();
const assetListIsFetched = ref(false);

assetStore.fetchAssetList().then(() => {
  assetListIsFetched.value = true;
});
</script>
```

This is the component with  where the store data is displayed

```
<template>
  <div>
    <q-table
      :rows="assetList"
      row-key="itemUuid"
      :columns="columns"
      @row-click="handleRowClick"
      rowsPerPage="10"
      :pagination="initialPagination"
    />
  </div>
  <div></div>
</template>

<style lang="scss"></style>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { useRouter } from 'vue-router';
import { useAssetStore } from 'src/stores/assetStore';
import { storeToRefs } from 'pinia';

const assetStore = useAssetStore();
const { assetList } = storeToRefs(assetStore);
```

I hope I have shown all the code related to this issue.
Where does the warning come from and how do I fix it?
I would appreciate any ideas or advice. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The code doesn't contain recursive updates

Comment: Thank you I think the problem lies elsewhere, where I did not even expect it.